# Need to fix a simple loop

Tags: c++

Okay I need to write a function that takes an integer parameter and prints the sum of each number up to that point. For example, n = 10 would be 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10.

```
int SumOneToN(int n)
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x <= n)
    {
        cout << x+(x+1) << " ";
        x++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

So what's going on here?
1. Set up the function as SumOneToN.
2. Initialize x to 0.
3. Create a while loop that states while x is less than our parameter, we take x, add it to x+1 (so that we get our current x value added to the next one), print it, then we add to x for the loop to go again until we meet the parameter.

That's how I thought it should work, anyways. What actually returns is:

1 3 5 7.. etc

I'm not sure where I went wrong?

Comment: Hint: there should be a variable to store the sum.

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually return anything, as your compiler should tell you.

Comment: @YuHao - Be better to remember some maths. Do not need the loop

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
int SumOneToN(int n)
{
    int x = 1, sum=0;
    while (x <= n)
    {
        sum=sum+x; 
        cout << sum << " ";
        x++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why return 0? That's nonsensical, you should return the result that the function is meant to compute!

Comment: It should be `return sum;`.

Comment: he just wants to print the array upto that particular element.. if u want to return the sum till n then use "return sum"..

Comment: @HarichandanPulagam Then why not make it a `void` function and change its name to `printOneToN`?

Comment: Is recurrent relations out of the maths curriculum?

Comment: you are printing sum instead of x in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some maths an not have the loop in the first place?

i.e.

```
int SumToOne(int n) {

    return (n * (n + 1))/2;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - why loop when you don't need to? +1 for maths

Comment: @user1520427 - I managed to stay awake during that lesson about rabbits having sex

Comment: @Ed_Heal haha yeah, I can tell. Apparently nobody else managed to though :/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are using same variable for Sum & as looping variable

try this code

```
int add(int n)
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        sum=sum+i;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: ... but indent it first

Answer (score 0):

```
int SumOneToN(int n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int x=1;x<=n;x++)
    {
        sum+=x; 
        cout << sum << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the "+" sign in the inverted commas and cout x; once before the while loop. If you want to do it by SUM than you have to introduce another variable and the above solutions are fair enough.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int SumOneToN(int n)
{
    int x = 1;
    cout << x ;
    x++;
    while (x <= n)
    {
        cout << " + " << x ;
        x++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >>x;
    SumOneToN(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int SumOneToN(int n){
    int sum=n,x=1;
    while(x<n){
        cout<<x<<"+";
        sum+=x;
        x++;
    }
    cout<<x;
    return sum;
}
```

Note: This wont print an additional '+' after last number.